# horizontal scroll bar appearance on web page with change in screen resolution

Tags: javascript, html, css

What is the correct CSS to remove the horizontal scroll bar appearing on the web page with changes in resolution ?

Has the width to be fixed to does it have to be in %?
Also, is the position to be kept absolute or relative ?
Please help - also are there any pointers for best CSSdesign across the browsers and when site is opened on phone ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There could be many scenarios leading to this issue,

Most common one is that you have defined a parent element (most probably a div) with width of 100% and then you have added padding and margin to it.

have a look at this link :
http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_boxmodel.asp

Other way is to create a responsive design (go with mobile first responsive design).
Read this for more info: http://designshack.net/articles/css/mobilefirst/

Finally I would recommend you use a css frame work. there are many out there and each has it's pros and cons. I personally prefer Bootstrap : http://getbootstrap.com/

Answer (score 0):

you could do a `overflow-x:hidden;` on the elements you want to hide the scrollbar from

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the responses, solved this my removing the fixed width of div in CSS which was causing problem